# Email validation with edu domains only

Tags: php, email-validation

i have been trying to get the email address which has domains ends with .edu only using code below

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$school = substr($email, strpos($email, "@") + 1);
```

is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Should be work for get your domain name and domain extension:

```
 $email = 'test@website.edu';
$getDomain = explode('@', $email);
$explValue = explode('.', $getDomain[1], 2);
print_r($explValue);
```

The out put is:

```
Array ( [0] => website [1] => edu )
```

After that you can check with

```
if($explValue[1] == 'edu'){
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make a substring including the last 3 chars of the current string.

```
<?php
$tld = substr($email, strlen($email)-2, 3);    // three last chars of the string
if ($tld = "edu") {
    // do stuff
}
?>
```

Comment: It won't work for `edu.pl` tld in Poland for instance.

Comment: Sure, i assumed he was fishing for the .edu top-level domain (was not specified in the question). The code must be adapted to any custom situation, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

If `.edu` is the last part of the email address, you could use [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$email = "test@test.edu";
$end = ".edu";
$string_end = substr($email, strlen($email) - strlen($end));
if ($end === $string_end) {
    // Ok
}
```

Maybe it is also an option to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and split on `@`. Then use explode again and split on a dot and check if the array returned contains `edu`:

```
$strings = [
    "test@test.edu",
    "test@test.edu.pl",    
    "test@test.com"
];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (in_array("edu", explode(".", explode("@", $string)[1]))) {
        // Etc..
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/6e9sH)

Answer (score -1):

`strpos($email, ".edu.");` it should be work.
for example gensek@metu.edu.tr

Answer (score -1):

You can use [substr](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp) And get last 4 characters if this is valid as per your requirement so the email is valid else it not.

```
$string = "xyzasd.edu";
echo $txt = substr($string,-4);

if($txt == ".edu"){
    //Valid
}else{
    //Not Valid
}
```

Comment: `domains ends with .edu only` And this code can be work